# What is this icon called?

Tags: android, icons, drawable

I want to include this icon in my Android app but I don't know what it is called. Here is the icon:

[image]

I tried to find it in @android:drawable and in the icon pack from Google but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called `ic_action_new` and you can find it in the icon pack on http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html (http://developer.android.com/downloads/design/Android_Design_Icons_20131106.zip) in the folder `Action Bar Icons\holo_light\01_core_new\drawable-hdpi\ic_action_new.png`.

[image: ic action new android icon]

Answer (score 3):

The answer above is correct, but keep in mind that if you just reference an android drawable, they can change them at any point. It might be safer to just download that drawable on your own, especially if you want any control on it aesthetically. The [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) will let you color it any way you want, and also download it in all of the varios dpi sizes.

Comment: Yes, but as I am still new to StackOverflow, I am not allowed to add comments to the existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is, download it, put it under `/drawable/`, then you can find it by `getDrawable()`

Answer (score 0):

**Pulling down from a URL:**

```
//Creates an http connection
HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
httpConnection .setRequestProperty("User-agent","Mozilla/4.0");
httpConnection .connect();

//Pulls down the image
InputStream input = httpConnection .getInputStream();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

//Creates a drawable from the bitmap
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
```

**Using local file in res/drawable/icon.png**

```
Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.icon );
```